# how to remove this title from my android application

Tags: android, edit

this is my app :
http://ge.tt/api/1/files/1GS1TFA2/0/blob?download

as you see in this screenshot, i need to remove this title from all tabs :
http://drp.io:8080/files/42e423e6e71e326156ee22445d90a482.png

there are other titles on the other tabs on app :
http://drp.io:8080/files/93e6c9bff3a0d0754a02869912720b51.png

i can attach any file from the app source code.

Comment: Please post the code of your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Your question isn't clear but try to check my answer, i provided both solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are coding in native Java, I think its in res/layout/yourfile.xml 
You should find the string you want to change. If it's not, check res/values/strings.xml file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it programmatically add this before setContentView:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

If you want to remove it from manifest, change the theme in this into your manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
  actionBar.hide();
```